# window.confirm not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a confirm box that is supposed to pop up in IE:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="return doAction('add')">Add User</button>
```

And my JavaScript:

```js
if ( action == "add" ) {
    if ( confirm( 'Action: Add User\n\nNetid: ' + id + '\n\n' + 'Name: ' + name ) ) {
        addUser( id );
    }
else {

}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens in IE. The button stays selected (highlighted blue), like the alert box is popped up. When I open the developer console, the confirm box works.

Is there a setting I need to allow confirm boxes in IE?

This works properly on every other browser.

Comment: If you've got any `console.log()` calls, they won't work unless the developer tools are open (in IE). They'll cause errors instead.

Comment: And I do. Right before the alert box. I'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer, and on which platform? @Pointy That issue has been resolved in modern version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I understand that - however the clue was that the OP said that the code works with the developer console open. Of course that might be a red herring.

Comment: IE 11. I removed my console.log()s and it worked. Thanks. It's hard to troubleshoot something like that when every time you open your console, the error goes away :/

Comment: @jordaniac89 This *shouldn't* cause the issue you're reporting. Can you share a more complete picture of your code so I can have our team (I work on the IE team) investigate further?

Comment: @JonathanSampson does IE11 still have "act like IE8" mode? That could be a contributing factor.

Comment: @Pointy It does, but I don't think *that* behavior was preserved in the IE 8 Document Mode. I'm struggling to replicate the issue in IE 11 *in any document mode*.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Sure thing. I'll try to get you the entire code tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a curly bracket

```
  if(action == "add"){
        if (confirm('Action: Add User\n\nNetid: ' + id + '\n\n' + 'Name: ' + name)){
           addUser(id);
        }
  }
  else {
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, just a copy/paste error. I think it's the console.log in the first comment.